# Apache Mina tutorial

Tags: apache, netbeans

I am tearing my hair out trying to figure out how to run the simplest Apache Mina tutorial.

I am running the tutorial on Netbeans 6.9 on Ubuntu and it keeps saying the following error
even I have added the necessary jar files to the compile-time libraries folders in Netbeans.

> Exception in thread "main"
>   java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
>           at minatimeserver.MinaTimeServer.main(MinaTimeServer.java:29)
>   Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   Uncompilable source code - package
>   org.slf4j does not exist
>           at org.apache.mina.core.service.AbstractIoService.(AbstractIoService.java:51)
>           ... 1 more

I have downloaded slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar and slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar and placed them in the compile-time libraries folder too but the error still remains. I have also tried with slf4j-1.5.11

Any person who has solved this problem? Please help me or I'm going bald in no time!

Thanks in advance!
Yakult121

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar` and `slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar` are runtime libraries.
Add them to your class path not to your compile-time libraries else it will try to compile your jar files.

*Also See*
[What's the difference of compile time libraries and run time libraries in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3090062/whats-the-difference-of-compile-time-libraries-and-run-time-libraries-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

Apache mina uses slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar, adding slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar to class path will resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I also had faced same problem. What I did was, I unjarred the mina-core-2.x that is on the main page of the apache project. When things failed, I changed downloaded mina-core-1.1.7 and everything worked fine. Of course, you have to make sure that you set the claspath correctly.